# Where does the favicon come from this website

Tags: html, favicon

I was inspecting this particular website : https://www.fertoret.fr/

And I was wondering where does the favicon come from as there isn't one specified in the header.

I'm probably missing some (new ?) feature, but which one ?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being able to specify the location of the favicon with a `<link>` is the new feature.

The original approach (which is used here) is to simply put the file at the URL `/favicon.ico` and let the browser request it (and so log files were filled with 404 errors).